# A forest tree exceeds TeX input stack size = 5000

Tags: forest, memory

I am using forest `2015/07/15 v1.0.10` in texlive-pictures `2015.38755`.

The code below

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{forest}
% parsing tree
\forestset{
  parsing tree/.style={
    declare toks={wff}{},
    declare toks={connective}{},
    for tree={
      math content,
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
    where level=0{
      for children={no edge},
      phantom
    }{
      delay={
        content=\circ,
        insert before/.wrap pgfmath arg={[##1,no edge,math content]}{wff()},
        if={strequal(connective(),"")}{connective/.option=wff}{},
        insert after/.wrap pgfmath arg={[##1,no edge,math content]}{connective()}
      },
      if n children=1{calign=child edge}{}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  parsing tree
  [
    [,wff=p_0]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

causes the following error

```
ERROR: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

--- TeX said ---
\pgfmathresult ->{\pgfmathresult 
                                 }{}
l.65 \end{forest}
```

It seems that the presence of `if={strequal(connective(),"")}{connective/.option=wff}{}` causes the error.

How do I diagnose and fix the error?

**Update 1** : After applying the suggestions of Sašo Živanović, I got the following code which works.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{forest}
% parsing tree
\forestset{
  declare toks={wff}{},
  declare toks={connective}{},
  parsing tree/.style={
    for tree={
      math content,
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
    where level=0{
      for children={no edge},
      phantom
    }{
      delay={
        content=\circ,
        insert before/.wrap pgfmath arg={[##1,no edge,math content]}{wff()},
        if connective={}{connective/.pgfmath=wff()}{},
        insert after/.wrap pgfmath arg={[##1,no edge,math content]}{connective()}
      },
      if n children=1{calign=child edge}{}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  parsing tree
  [
    [,wff=p_0]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A detective story. You are right, this line is the (final) culprit:

```
if={strequal(connective(),"")}{connective/.option=wff}{},
```

Chain of events, in reverse order:

- Pgfmath enters infinite recursion as `\pgfmathresult` expands to `\pgfmathresult`
- Why? Because `\pgfmathresult` was `\let` to `\relax`. (I don't know how pgfmath gets from `\relax` to infinite recursion. This has to do with its internals. But it seems clear that `\pgfmathresult` should never be set to `\relax` as a return value of a pgfmath function.)
- Who did that? Obviously pgfmath function of option `connective`.
- Why? Because its value is undefined.
- Why? Because the option was declared after the nodes were already created.

Moral of the story: declare options outside the tree. In the present case, outside the style:

```
\forestset{
  declare toks={wff}{},
  declare toks={connective}{},
  parsing tree/.style={
   ...
```

By the way, you can use the specialized conditional `if connective` instead of the generic `if`. It's faster (to execute *and* type:)

```
if connective={}{connective/.option=wff}{},
```

Comment: `if connective={}{connective/.option=wff}{}` causes an error, `ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/forest/connective/.option', to which you passed 'wff', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` I am using forest `2015/07/15 v1.0.10` in texlive-pictures `2015.38755` provided by manjaro linux.

Comment: Somehow, `if connective={}{connective/.pgfmath=wff()}{}` is fine.

Comment: `.option` handler was only introduced in v2.0 ... time to update! ;-)

Comment: As far as I know, I can't update without manually compiling texlive. And, I'm not ready to take on the daunting task of manual compilation. Is there an easier alternative?

Comment: @crocket You don't need to manually compile anything unless you are using a *very* unusual platform. You can install manually using upstream's installer, but everything is pre-compiled. Binaries are supplied for a very wide range of platforms. Including yours.

Comment: Ok, I found https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texlive-localmanager-git/.